# invalid iterator after STL vector erase

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Even though I looked at that page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/ ,
I still don't understand why I am having a runtime error on VS2010 ('vector iterator not incrementable') when executing the last line of the following code:

```
vector<int> vec;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    vec.push_back(i);
auto itb = vec.begin()+1;  // 2nd item of the vector
auto it  = itb + 2;        // 4th item of the vector
it = vec.erase(itb, it);   // remove the 2nd & 3rd
++it; // Error happens when trying to execute this line
```

I thought erase would return an iterator on the item that is just after the last removed one.
So, here it would be pointing on item with value 3.
Here, as the vector is long enough erase doesn't return vec.end().
From there, I should be able to iterate with a valid iterator.
But no!
Why?

Whereas that code works:

```
vector<int> vec;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    vec.push_back(i);
auto itb = vec.begin()+1;
auto it = itb + 2;
vec.erase(itb, it);
it = vec.begin()+1; // re-generate an iterator from the begin() one.
++it;
```

**Edit:**
If I slightly modify the code from "Vlad from Moscow" (see below) in an empty main.cpp file, then I am still having the problem. So, I guess I have a compiler issue.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) v.push_back( i );

    for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end() ; ++it ) std::cout << *it << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto itb = v.begin() + 1;
    auto it = itb + 2;

    it = v.erase( itb, it );

    ++it;  // Crash here

    for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end() ; ++it ) std::cout << *it << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    while ( it != v.end() ) std::cout << *it++ << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Let me describe my config:
I am running a Win7 Ultimate 64bit under Parallel desktop (Mac), with VC++6, VCS2003, VS2005, VS2008, VS2010 (no SP, .Net framework 4.5) installed.

Comment: Do keep in mind your loop could just be a call to `std::iota`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. Are you sure it's the one you're running?

Comment: If the program crashes on that line with the snippet above, you probably have undefined behaviour elsewhere that corrupts the memory.

Comment: Did you check `it != vec.end()` just in case? Try printing `it` after erase.

Comment: are you using a weird compiler? otherwise you're corrupting the iterator somewhere else.

Comment: @chris: It was just to create a simple example, but thank you because I did not know that STL function. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This example demonstrates that there is nothing wrong in your first code snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) v.push_back( i );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto itb = v.begin() + 1;
    auto it = itb + 2;

    it = v.erase( itb, it );

    ++it;

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    while ( it != v.end() ) std::cout << *it++ << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 5 6 7 8 9
```

If to remove statement

```
    ++it;
```

then the output will be

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

EDIT: Here is the same program running in MS VC++ 2010

```
#include    "stdafx.h"
#include    <iostream>
#include    <vector>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) v.push_back( i );

    for each ( int x in v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto itb = v.begin() + 1;
    auto it = itb + 2;

    it = v.erase( itb, it );

    ++it;

    for each ( int x in v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    while ( it != v.end() ) std::cout << *it++ << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I hope these examples will help you to find your real error.

Comment: I guess I am having a compiler issue because I tried your upper code (slightly modified to not use the "automatic loop" for printing), and I still have the same issue.

Comment: @OhMyCode  My post contains an example running in MS VS 2010. So maybe the reason in your modifications. Another reason may be is that the compiler uses a wrong header.

Comment: yes, but I was lazy to recreate a project. So, I just #if 0/#endif my code and put your first one (as I always disable the stdafx.h stuff because my code needs to be portable). Otherwise, the "vector." file it crashes from is located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include".